# Understanding flow of object creation

Tags: java

I'm new to java and I wonder if there is simple way to know flow like the following of object creation, I'm using eclipse and when I write `new ObjectInputStream` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>.
I don't see any option that I can enter new BufferedInputStream (I have copied the code from example) and than to create new object for FileInputStream etc.

```
in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("emp.dat")));
List temp = (List)in.readObject();
```

I give that example since this is the first time that I saw this kind of creation new object flow and I want to use some best practice for the next times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple. This is equivalent to :

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("emp.dat");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis)
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
```

As you are new to Java, you should check [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) instead of checking it in Eclipse.

Check : [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html), [BufferedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html), [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic example of using `[Decorator Pattern][1]`. You will wrap objects to add  behavior.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shows you options you have available at that point to get the options you might value if you created something you have to type `new` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

BTW: ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream are already buffered so adding more buffering isn't best practice IMHO.